# android can't connect to local domain via shadowsocks

Tags: android, vpn, dnsmasq

I have a server with `shadowsocks-libev`, `dnsmasq` and `nginx`.

Dnsmasq configured with `address=/my.domain/127.0.0.1` and availabel only for requests from localhost.
Nginx configured with `server_name .my.domain`. This allows me to connect to my private web-page through shadowsocks.

On my Linux machines, all work well: I have local socks5-proxy and can use it in any software (ex. Firefox).

But it doesn't work on Android. On my phone, I use official [shadowsocks-client](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.github.shadowsocks). And mobile Firefox can't connect to my secret page.

I enabled `--log-queries` in Dnsmasq's config and saw DNS requests go to it. And Dnsmasq's answers are correct (for Linux-connections it looks similar):

```
query[AAAA] my.domain from 127.0.0.1
config my.domain is ::1
query[A] my.domain from 127.0.0.1
config my.domain is 127.0.0.1
```

Also, I tried [IP Tools](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ddm.iptools). And its "Lookup" tool gets the correct answer.

What wrong with my phone? Or maybe a problem on server?

My phone based on :

- Resurrection Remix LP v5.5.9
- Android version 5.1.1
- Shadowsocks 4.8.4